# SQL query to get merged result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the result from a table using MySQL query. What I want to do is I am trying to fetch 20 records from the table. In these 20 records, first 15 records must be in ascending order and the last 5 records must be in descending order. I am trying but I am not getting a way to get this done.

I don't know how to write sub queries.

Thanks.

Comment: So... if your table had numbers from `1` to `100` what would be your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`

```
(SELECT *
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY column_name 
 LIMIT 15)
 UNION ALL
(SELECT *
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY column_name DESC
 LIMIT 5)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ddbf/3)** demo

Comment: This will not work, b/c last query will return first 5 result in descending order, so change it according to that, Limit 15,20

Comment: Hey peterm.. Thanks for replying so quick. But that is not working.. I am getting this error "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY". And my query is   "SELECT * FROM `blogaliys_options` ORDER BY `option_id` LIMIT 15 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `blogaliys_options` ORDER BY `option_id` DESC LIMIT 5"

Comment: @Yunus You need parentheses. See updated answer and sqlfiddle demo